# How to check which subview is currently displayed on screen in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subviews

I would like to check which subview is visible right now on screen or covered by other view , which I cannot do with the following condition.

```
if (viewController.isViewLoaded && viewController.view.window) {
  // viewController is visible
}
```

Could anyone give me example for a subview?

If viewController is the main controller where I add subviews, I like to check this condition for one of my subviews-child of this controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top most view by the follwoing code snippet

```
topMostSubView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
```

Usually this will give you the top view, but there's no guarantee that it's visible to the user. It could be off the screen, have an alpha of 0.0, or could be have size of 0x0 for example.

It could also be that the keyWindow has no subviews, so you should probably test for that first.

If you want to add another subview on the top most view, you can simply add it directly to the keyWindow using addSubview: and it will instantly be the top most view.